# Querying different components that inherit from the same one through @ContentChildren

Tags: angular, inheritance, typescript, angular2-template

I'm trying to querying a bunch of components that inherits from the same through ContentChildren:

```html
<app-inputs-container>
   <app-input-1></app-input-1>
   <app-input-2></app-input-2>
   <app-input-3></app-input-3>
<app-inputs-container>
```

```js
@Component({ selector: 'app-inputs-container', ... })
export class InputsContainerComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(BaseInputComponent) inputs;

  ngAfterContentInit() { console.log(this.inputs); }
}
```

All three inputs inherit from the same component:

```js
@Component({ selector: 'app-input-1', ... })
export class Input1Component extends BaseInputComponent {    }

@Component({ selector: 'app-input-2', ... })
export class Input2Component extends BaseInputComponent {    }

@Component({ selector: 'app-input-3', ... })
export class Input3Component extends BaseInputComponent {    }
```

But I get the `inputs` list empty.

Is anything missing by my side, or this behaviour is not supported by Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding forwarding providers to your component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inputs-container',
  providers: [
    {provide: BaseInputComponent, useExisting: Input1Component, multi: true}
    {provide: BaseInputComponent, useExisting: Input2Component, multi: true}
    {provide: BaseInputComponent, useExisting: Input3Component, multi: true}
  ]
})
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've exactly the same problem. But in my case there can be `n` number of inherited components. Is it possible to add forwarding providers dynamically?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible.